the change is not auto-integrated to main from patch codeline
Recently we made an e-release change in 250/prod (refer to https://swarm.soma.salesforce.com/changes/48710257). And it was auto-integrated into 250/freeze, 250/patch. 252/patch, but not into main (refer to https://swarm.soma.salesforce.com/changes/48711618).
Could you help resolve the auto-integration to main? Thanks! Here is a list of the auto-integrations: https://gus.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/ADM_Work__c/a07EE000020bixSYAQ/related/WorkChangeLists__r/view
N/A. It is about auto-integration.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
